# Mini Ajax file upload form

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload

I'm using [Ajax Mini File Upload Form](http://tutorialzine.com/2013/05/mini-ajax-file-upload-form/) to allow users to drag'n'drop files to upload to the server.

Client side the form and the script are the same, the difference is in the upload.php.

In order to allow the upload the user needs credentials. And i can't find out how to add sending login and password to the upload.php page.

Edit :

I've tried reading the source code to understand where i could add the parameters i need, but so far i've only found that the parameters are stored in formData.

Since i'm in a rush, i've hardcoded the login and password in the upload page so i could continue coding on the server side (it's the current focus) until i can add code client side to include those 2 parameters.

Below is only the html part of the page with the main script since all the scripts are too big to post here

```
<div id="AuthForm" class="div_border">
    <p>You need to login in order to use the servicer</p>
    <label>Login :</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="auth_login"><br>
    <label>Password :</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="auth_password"><br/><br/>
    <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="lf_login();">
</div>
```

Above is the div containing the login form from which i get the login and password

```
<div id="AdminTest" class="div_border">
    <form id="upload" method="post" action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div id="drop">
            Drop Here

            <a>Browse</a>
            <input type="file" name="upl" multiple />
        </div>

        <ul>
            <!-- The file uploads will be shown here -->
        </ul>

    </form>
</div>
```

Above is the form used by the script to upload files.

```
$(function(){

var ul = $('#upload ul');

$('#drop a').click(function(){
    // Simulate a click on the file input button
    // to show the file browser dialog
    $(this).parent().find('input').click();
});

// Initialize the jQuery File Upload plugin
$('#upload').fileupload({

    // This element will accept file drag/drop uploading
    dropZone: $('#drop'),

    // This function is called when a file is added to the queue;
    // either via the browse button, or via drag/drop:
    add: function (e, data) {

        var tpl = $('<li class="working"><input type="text" value="0" data-width="48" data-height="48"'+
            ' data-fgColor="#0788a5" data-readOnly="1" data-bgColor="#3e4043" /><p></p><span></span></li>');

        // Append the file name and file size
        tpl.find('p').text(data.files[0].name)
                     .append('<i>' + formatFileSize(data.files[0].size) + '</i>');

        // Add the HTML to the UL element
        data.context = tpl.appendTo(ul);

        // Initialize the knob plugin
        tpl.find('input').knob();

        // Listen for clicks on the cancel icon
        tpl.find('span').click(function(){

            if(tpl.hasClass('working')){
                jqXHR.abort();
            }

            tpl.fadeOut(function(){
                tpl.remove();
            });

        });

        // Automatically upload the file once it is added to the queue
        var jqXHR = data.submit();
    },

    progress: function(e, data){

        // Calculate the completion percentage of the upload
        var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);

        // Update the hidden input field and trigger a change
        // so that the jQuery knob plugin knows to update the dial
        data.context.find('input').val(progress).change();

        if(progress == 100){
            data.context.removeClass('working');
        }
    },

    fail:function(e, data){
        // Something has gone wrong!
        data.context.addClass('error');
    }

});


// Prevent the default action when a file is dropped on the window
$(document).on('drop dragover', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});

// Helper function that formats the file sizes
function formatFileSize(bytes) {
    if (typeof bytes !== 'number') {
        return '';
    }

    if (bytes >= 1000000000) {
        return (bytes / 1000000000).toFixed(2) + ' GB';
    }

    if (bytes >= 1000000) {
        return (bytes / 1000000).toFixed(2) + ' MB';
    }

    return (bytes / 1000).toFixed(2) + ' KB';
}

});
```

Above is the main script that uses jquery.fileUpload script in order to upload files.

Comment: code examples? what have you tried so far?http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Well i tried reading the scripts script.js and jquery.fileupload.js in order to try to understand what is done inside. So far i've understood that formData is where data is stored and where i should add login and password data. However i can't find at what point i should do that.

Comment: Please edit your question, and show what you have done so far/tried so far, maybe show even a demo page/jsfiddle something like that. Your question is very abstract and its impossible to help you as the question stands now